# MySQL select statement result in after delete trigger always null

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I'm having a little issue with a trigger in a MySQL database. I have a DB with two tables: "tasks" and "files". The "tasks" table have a field which is a foreign key of the primary key from the "files" table. It also sometimes may be null.

What I'm trying to acomplish is to delete in the first place a row in the "tasks" table, and after that delete the corresponding row in the "files" table using a trigger.

This is the trigger I'm using right now:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_delete_file AFTER DELETE ON tasks
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE fileId int;
    SELECT file INTO fileId FROM tasks WHERE id=old.id;
    DELETE FROM files WHERE id=fileId;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

The field "file" in the "tasks" table is the one containing the foreign key. In the examples I've been running, that field has never been null.

The problem is that the select statement always returns null. The delete statement that triggers this trigger goes fine, but the row in the "files" table is never deleted. I've tried to insert the "fieldId" variable on a testing table, and it's always saving a null value.

Is there any problem on that trigger? Maybe I'm trying to do something merely impossible?

All the help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it should be looping over each deleted row, why would this not work?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_delete_file AFTER DELETE ON tasks
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM files WHERE id=old.file;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

If that doesn't work, could try this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_delete_file AFTER DELETE ON tasks
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM files INNER JOIN tasks ON files.id=tasks.file WHERE tasks.id=old.id;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

but I don't think that should be necessary.

Comment: Hi!

Yes, is what I just realized reading moreOn's answer. I can't believe I didn't thinks of that earlier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AFTER delete means that the data is deleted, of course you can't find it. Try creating the trigger for BEFORE delete.

You could also more carefully use all of the old values rather than selecting from the table that was deleted from.

Comment: I thought that, although it was an After delete, I could be able to find it since the transaction is not finished until the after trigger is finished.

I can't use a Before trigger cause I can't delete the row on the "files" table before the deletion on the "tasks" table, it's a foreign key to that table. And I think it doesn't makes sense to set it to "on delete cascade".

I think I have found a solution accessing to old.file to make the deletion on the trigger. Is that what you meant on the second sentence? I didn't got to completely understood what you meant.